# admob adds aren't showing up in android eclipse please help

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

[image: .java file]

[image: new screenshot of manifest]

.java file code

```
        package com.soundboard;

import com.soundboard.SoundManager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.google.ads.*;

public class Soundboard extends Activity {
    private SoundManager mSoundManager;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14e2748a80b0ac");
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        layout.addView(adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());


                // Create the adView
                AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, a14e2748a80b0ac);
                // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
                // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
                LinearLayout layout = (LinearyLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
                // Add the adView to it
                layout.addView(adView);
                // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
                adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
              }
            }




        mSoundManager = new SoundManager();
        mSoundManager.initSounds(getBaseContext());
        mSoundManager.addSound(1, R.raw.sound1);
        mSoundManager.addSound(2, R.raw.sound2);
        mSoundManager.addSound(3, R.raw.sound3);
        mSoundManager.addSound(4, R.raw.sound4);
        mSoundManager.addSound(5, R.raw.sound5);
        mSoundManager.addSound(6, R.raw.sound6);
        mSoundManager.addSound(7, R.raw.sound7);
        mSoundManager.addSound(8, R.raw.sound8);
        mSoundManager.addSound(9, R.raw.sound9);
        mSoundManager.addSound(10, R.raw.sound10);
        mSoundManager.addSound(11, R.raw.sound11);
        mSoundManager.addSound(12, R.raw.sound12);
        mSoundManager.addSound(13, R.raw.sound13);
        mSoundManager.addSound(14, R.raw.sound14);
        mSoundManager.addSound(15, R.raw.sound15);
        mSoundManager.addSound(16, R.raw.sound16);
        mSoundManager.addSound(17, R.raw.sound17);
        mSoundManager.addSound(18, R.raw.sound18);
        mSoundManager.addSound(19, R.raw.sound19);
        mSoundManager.addSound(20, R.raw.sound20);
        mSoundManager.addSound(21, R.raw.sound21);
        mSoundManager.addSound(22, R.raw.sound22);
        mSoundManager.addSound(23, R.raw.sound23);
        mSoundManager.addSound(24, R.raw.sound24);
        mSoundManager.addSound(25, R.raw.sound25);
        mSoundManager.addSound(26, R.raw.sound26);
        mSoundManager.addSound(27, R.raw.sound27);
        mSoundManager.addSound(28, R.raw.sound28);
        mSoundManager.addSound(29, R.raw.sound29);
        mSoundManager.addSound(30, R.raw.sound30);


        Button SoundButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound1);
        SoundButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSoundManager.playSound(1);

    }
});       
        Button SoundButton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound2);
        SoundButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSoundManager.playSound(2);

    }
});    
        Button SoundButton3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound3);
        SoundButton3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSoundManager.playSound(3);

    }
});    
        Button SoundButton4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound4);
        SoundButton4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSoundManager.playSound(4);

    }
});    
        Button SoundButton5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound5);
        SoundButton5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSoundManager.playSound(5);

    }
});   
        Button SoundButton6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound6);
        SoundButton6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSoundManager.playSound(6);

    }
});    
        Button SoundButton7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound7);
        SoundButton7.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSoundManager.playSound(7);

    }
});
  Button SoundButton8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound8);
       SoundButton8.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSoundManager.playSound(8);

    }
 });    
        Button SoundButton9 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound9);
        SoundButton9.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSoundManager.playSound(9);

    }
});    
       Button SoundButton10 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound10);
       SoundButton10.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSoundManager.playSound(10);

    }
 });    
        Button SoundButton11 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound11);
        SoundButton11.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSoundManager.playSound(11);

    }
});    
        Button SoundButton12 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound12);
        SoundButton12.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSoundManager.playSound(12);

    }
});    
       Button SoundButton13 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound13);
       SoundButton13.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSoundManager.playSound(13);

    }
 });    
        Button SoundButton14 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound14);
        SoundButton14.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mSoundManager.playSound(14);

    }
});    

        Button SoundButton15 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound15);
                SoundButton15.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSoundManager.playSound(15);

            }
        });
                Button SoundButton16 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound16);
                SoundButton16.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSoundManager.playSound(16);

            }
        });    
                Button SoundButton17 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound17);
                SoundButton17.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSoundManager.playSound(17);

            }
        });    
                Button SoundButton18 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound18);
                SoundButton18.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSoundManager.playSound(18);

            }
        });    
                Button SoundButton19 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound19);
                SoundButton19.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSoundManager.playSound(19);

            }
        });    
                Button SoundButton20 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound20);
                SoundButton20.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSoundManager.playSound(20);

            }
        });    
               Button SoundButton21 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound21);
                SoundButton21.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSoundManager.playSound(21);

            }
       });    
                Button SoundButton22 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound22);
                SoundButton22.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSoundManager.playSound(22);

            }
        });    
                Button SoundButton23 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound23);
                SoundButton23.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSoundManager.playSound(23);

            }
        });    
                Button SoundButton24 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound24);
                SoundButton24.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSoundManager.playSound(24);

            }
        });    
                Button SoundButton25 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound25);
                SoundButton25.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSoundManager.playSound(25);

            }
        });    
                Button SoundButton26 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound26);
                SoundButton26.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSoundManager.playSound(26);

            }
        });    
                Button SoundButton27 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound27);
                SoundButton27.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSoundManager.playSound(27);

            }
        });    
                Button SoundButton28 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound28);
                SoundButton28.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSoundManager.playSound(28);

            }
        });    
                Button SoundButton29 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound29);
                SoundButton29.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSoundManager.playSound(29);

            }
        });    
                Button SoundButton30 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sound30);
                SoundButton30.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mSoundManager.playSound(30);

            }
        });    

    }
}
```

I have also included the code from my .xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/tablelayout1"
android:layout_width="312px"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<Button
android:id="@+id/sound1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 1"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 2"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 3"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound4"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 4"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound5"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 5"
>
</Button>
<Button android:text="Sound Button 6" android:id="@+id/sound6" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound7"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sount Button 7"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound8"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 8"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound9"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound Button 8"
>
</Button>

<Button
android:id="@+id/sound10"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 10"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound11"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 11"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound12"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 12"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound13"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 13"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound14"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 14"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound15"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 15"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound16"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 16"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound17"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 17"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound18"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 18"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound19"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 19"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound20"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 20"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound21"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 21"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound22"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 22"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound23"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 23"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound24"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 24"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound25"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 25"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound26"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound Button 26"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound27"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 27"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound28"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 28"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound29"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 29"
>
</Button>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sound30"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Sound button 30"
>
</Button>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

figured i'd just give some screenshots to make it painless.

I get the three errors there on my soundboard.java page.  At this point I am merely trying to manipulate my code so there are no errors and I can atempt to run this in the emulator.

3 errors on the one line now.

1. Multiple markers at this line

   - LinearLayout cannot be resolved 
     to a type
   - layout1 cannot be resolved or is 
     not a field
   - LinearLayout cannot be resolved 
     to a type

Can anyone tell what im doin wrong?  Thanks

I just tried to follow the familiar tutorial on the google website:

http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html#addadview

[image: new ss of .java with only 1 error now :)]

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you are having?

Comment: Did you add the .jar file to your /lib directory, then Refresh in the project explorer in Eclipse, and right-click on the .jar file and select "Add to Build Path"?

Comment: I did the properties > java build path > add external jars > and selected the .jar this way and hit ok.  Then it came to its current spot as shown in the screenshot.  Is that ok? Or do I have to put it in a libs folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the onCreate in your SoundBoard class to:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14e2748a80b0ac");
  LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
  layout.addView(adView);
  adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

  mSoundManager = new SoundManager();
  mSoundManager.initSounds(getBaseContext());

  // The rest of the soundManager code you've written
}
```

Remove the whole BannerExample class, with the admob code inside it, you only need it once, the extra brackets were closing the onCreate method and the class.

You also need to import LinearLayout, just press ctrl + o, or cmd+o, in eclipse for it to import the classes you need.

You needed "" around the admob id.

I have used R.id.LinearLayout1 because that is the name of your LinearLayout in the xml class, which is why mainLayout wasn't working.

Comment: I have tried pasting that in a few ways and keep getting errors :/ Im not sure how to put it in or what to get rid of.  Is the inner class your refering to the public class?...Just not sure what to get rid of.  Thanks so much for help

Comment: i there any way you can show my how my .java file should look? I will post the code above.  Thanks

Comment: ok that file is fine, just get rid of the whole BannerExample class. Then replace it with:
  AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14e2748a80b0ac");
  LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
  layout.addView(adView);
  adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

Comment: ok, I changed the code around.  And I still get errors :/ I have edited the post and paste the new code into the .java file area again.  Although I pasted in the code as you showed, I was unable to add the bracket ( { ) in to it because I was unsure of where exactly to put it.  I have also updated the errors that I get and am posting a new screenshot of the .java file in eclipse.  Thanks!

Comment: ok same issue, you didn't remove the code inside the old BannerExample class, I'm editing my answer to show you where to start your soundboard calls

Comment: ok kool thanks for all your help...down to just one error on my linear layout class.  Any ideas?  I posted a screenshot at bottom.

Comment: just import it like it says, and change the id to R.id.LinearLayout1, I must've misread the xml file first time round when I said layout1

Comment: ok great. Good news and bad. Got it without errors and running in the emulator, however no ads or anything comes up...and I let it run in the emulator for like 10 mins. Thanks for help...wish I knew what was wrong...

Comment: does it matter that this package name isn't the same as the one from which I am using the admob id?

Comment: that might be the issue, but I'm not entirely sure, you should try using the admob id for this package, if you've set the application up. Have you tried running the app on an actual phone?

Comment: have not tried...i actually dont have an android phone lol...and now when i switched the name I can't get it to run in the emulator...what the heck...the emulator just goes to the phone home screen when i unlock

Comment: if you changed the package name in eclipse, did you update all the references? Also, you may need to make changes in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: yea updated all the references i believe...all the java files, the .r, and the manifest.. and it runs before i go to change the names...then after i attempt to change package names it doesn't show up in emulator..but theres no errors anywhere after i change the name

Comment: you could try uninstalling the app in the emulator and then trying again, or cleaning and rebuilding the project

Comment: ok I fiddled and got the app to show up in the emulator...now the only thing is the adds won't show up with the code...I think I am going to make a new thread similar to this one... I'm gona call it "Admob adds will not show up in running emulator" i'd love for more input and help...thanks for everything man

Comment: no worries, I'm not sure if the admob ads show up in the emulator so that could be the issue, but that's just me clutching at straws to be honest, though I'd appreciate it if you could accept this answer, as it would close this question, once you get the next one opened up

Comment: lol i will def...just one more favor, i upload the new update.  Can u check and see if it works. the app is free.  its called movie quoters soundboard.  Just trying to find out if the ads show.  and thanks for all ur help

Comment: I'm not getting any ads on the app :( The only thing I could see this being is the publisher id on admob and package names, but you've corrected those issues.. maybe try putting it in your table layout? but again I'm not entirely sure what the issue could be here, sorry!